# How to deal with v-for in vuejs when element has no id?

Tags: vuejs2

I often get this error related to the `v-for` directive.

> Elements in iteration expect to have `v-bind:key` directive

When using a for loop like this.

```
<div v-for='person in people'> {{ person.name }} </div>
```

The problem is, in sometimes in rare cases, I have no `id` key for person. And I want to know what can be done in this case.

Comment: Add index value to the key if there is no ID

Comment: You mean like:  `<div v-for='(person, index) in people'>`?

Comment: Yes like that and add index to the key

Comment: `<div v-for='(person, index) in people' :key="index"></div>` <-- like this

Answer (score 25, accepted):

As Ghanshyam already mentioned in comments, you can easily generate an index in `v-for`.

```
<div v-for="(person, index) in people" :key="index" >
    {{ person.name }}
</div>
```

[However, there is something to be said for **NOT** using index as a key.](https://medium.com/@robinpokorny/index-as-a-key-is-an-anti-pattern-e0349aece318)

Other SO Post: [Why not always use the index as the key in a vue.js for loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44531510/why-not-always-use-the-index-as-the-key-in-a-vue-js-for-loop)