# Vue for loop with index as key causes unpredictable behaviour

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, v-for

I have an array that is rendered as a set of Vue components using `v-for`. I need to use `:key=""` otherwise Vue complains.

My array has no unique identifiers so I use the index as the key

My loop

```
  <card v-for="(item, index) in questions" :question="item" :key="index">{{item}}</card>
```

The array has objects that can have the same contents

```
[{name:"jimmy"}, {name:"billy bob"}, {name:"jimmy"}]
```

The problem: as soon as I manipulate the array the results become very unpredictable. Sometimes the components are rendered correctly. Sometimes a new component appears in the middle of the `v-for` list even though it was pushed into the array. Sometimes, after a shift / pop, all the old components remain and the newly pushed one doesn't appear.

Code

```
if(this.questions.length > 4) this.questions.shift()
this.questions.push({name:"willy jim"})
```

If I use `item.name` as the key, it works perfectly fine so long as there are no duplicate names. If I use `item.name+index` or something so silly, the whole thing goes bonkers...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why not always use the index as the key in a vue.js for loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44531510/why-not-always-use-the-index-as-the-key-in-a-vue-js-for-loop)

Answer (score 1):

Using the *index* as a key is a not a good idea as the index will recalculate when the array changes.

For example you might have something like this on the first render:

```
<div key="0">Item 1</div>
<div key="1">Item 2</div>
<div key="2">Item 3</div>
<div key="3">Item 4</div>
```

But, if you then change the array, say you remove the 2nd item, the index of each item will change so you end up with this:

```
<div key="0">Item 1</div>
<div key="1">Item 3</div>
<div key="2">Item 4</div>
```

...rather than:

```
<div key="0">Item 1</div>
<div key="2">Item 3</div>
<div key="3">Item 4</div>
```

If possible, it would be a good idea to give each item in your array an **id** and use that as the key instead:

```
[
  {
    id: 1,
    name:"jimmy"
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name:"billy bob"
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name:"jimmy"
  }
]
```