# Strange behavior of editable component re-ordering

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I have a table containing editable cells. You can add rows, columns and reorder them.

This is how my template is created:

```
<template>
  <div id="datatables-admin">
    <h1>Datatables admin</h1>

    <table id="editor">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th v-for="(column, index_col) in columns" :key="index_col">
            <i class="fas fa-long-arrow-alt-left fa-2x dta-btn move-col-left" title="Move column to left" v-on:click="move_col_to_left(index_col)"></i>
            <i class="fas fa-long-arrow-alt-right fa-2x dta-btn move-col-right" title="Move column to right" v-on:click="move_col_to_right(index_col)"></i>
            <i class="fas fa-plus fa-2x dta-btn add-col" title="Add a column after this one" v-on:click="add_col(index_col + 1)"></i>
            <i class="fas fa-times fa-2x dta-btn delete-col" title="Delete this column" v-on:click="delete_col(index_col)"></i>
            <br />
            <editable :content="columns[index_col]" v-on:update="update_col($event, index_col)"></editable>
          </th>
          <th>
            <i class="fas fa-plus fa-2x dta-btn add-col" title="Add a column" v-on:click="add_col(0)"></i>
            <i class="fas fa-plus fa-2x dta-btn add-row" title="Add a row" v-on:click="add_row(0)"></i>
            <i class="fas fa-times fa-2x dta-btn delete-all-cols" title="Delete all columns" v-on:click="delete_all_cols"></i>
            <i class="fas fa-times fa-2x dta-btn delete-all-rows" title="Delete all rows" v-on:click="delete_all_rows"></i>
          </th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr v-for="(row, index_row) in rows" :key="index_row">
          <td v-for="(column, index_col) in columns" :key="index_col">
            <editable :content="rows[index_row][index_col]" v-on:update="update_row($event, index_row, index_col)"></editable>
          <td>
            <i class="fas fa-long-arrow-alt-up fa-2x dta-btn move-row-up" v-on:click="move_row_up(index_row)" title="Move row up"></i>
            <i class="fas fa-long-arrow-alt-down fa-2x dta-btn move-row-down" v-on:click="move_row_down(index_row)" title="Move row down"></i>
            <i class="fas fa-plus fa-2x dta-btn add-row" title="Add a row under this one" v-on:click="add_row(index_row + 1)"></i>
            <i class="fas fa-times fa-2x dta-btn delete-row" title="Delete this row" v-on:click="delete_row(index_row)"></i>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>

    <div>
      <b>DEBUG:</b>
      <span v-text="rows"></span>
    </div>

    <table-preview></table-preview>
  </div>
</template>
```

Example of data (columns):

```
[ "Click me to edit", "Demo column 2", "Demo column 3", "URL" ]
```

Example of data (rows):

```
[ [ "col1 data1", "col2 data1", "col3 data1", "https://www.google.com" ], [ "col1 data2", "col2 data2", "col3 data2", "https://www.yahoo.com" ] ]
```

I'm new with Vue.js and I think I miss something very important, because I have this issue:

1. First render: OK
   [image]
2. Adding an empty row: OK
   [image]
3. Re-order the first 2 rows: OK
   [image]
4. Editing the texts in empty row: OK
   [image]
5. Now... Reorder first 2 rows: NOT OK
   I mean: the data is OK - as you can see in debug section, but the table in page is funny.
   [image]
6. Reorder: OK...
   [image]

The same issue for columns. This is very annoying, because I can't find any reason for this. If I put this question in Code Review they will say: we do review only for non-buggy code...

Can you suggest a solution for this issue? (I expect it is something familiar for Vue.js users.)

My code is here: https://github.com/GhitaB/datatables-admin

Live demo: https://ghitab.github.io/datatables-admin/

I hope someone will save my week.

Update:

Adding more code:

[main.js](https://github.com/GhitaB/datatables-admin/blob/master/src/main.js)

```
// The Vue build version to load with the `import` command
// (runtime-only or standalone) has been set in webpack.base.conf with an alias.
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App'

Vue.config.productionTip = false

Vue.component('editable', {
  template: `
    <div contenteditable="true" @blur="emitChange">
      {{ content }}
    </div>
  `,
  props: ['content'],
  methods: {
    emitChange(ev) {
      this.$emit('update', ev.target.textContent)
    }
  }
});

Vue.component('table-preview', {
  template: `
    <div class="table-preview-container">
      <button class='render-table' v-on:click="render_table">Preview table</button>
      <table class="table-render-preview"></table>
    </div>
  `,
  props: ['content'],
  methods: {
    render_table() {
      var columns = this.$parent.columns;
      var rows = this.$parent.rows;
      var table_placeholder = document.querySelector('.table-render-preview');

      function make_table_html(columns, rows) {
        function render_link(url) {
          if(url !== undefined) {
            return "<a href='" + url +"' target='_blank' title=" + url + ">Link<span style='display:none !important'>" + url + "</span></a>";
          } else {
            return "N/A";
          }
        }

        var result = "<table border=1><thead><tr>";

        for(var i = 0; i < columns.length; i++) {
          result += "<th>" + columns[i] + "</th>";
        }

        result += "</thead><tbody>"
        for(var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
          result += "<tr>";
          for(var j = 0; j < rows[i].length; j++) {
            if(columns[j] == "URL") {
              result += "<td>" +  render_link(rows[i][j]) + "</td>";
            } else {
              result += "<td>" + rows[i][j] + "</td>";
            }
          }
          result += "</tr>";
        }
        result += "</tbody></table>";

        return result;
      }

      if ($.fn.DataTable.isDataTable(".table-render-preview")) {
        $('.table-render-preview').DataTable().clear().destroy();
      }

      var new_el = document.createElement("table");
      new_el.className = "table-render-preview";
      new_el.innerHTML = make_table_html(columns, rows);
      table_placeholder.parentNode.replaceChild(new_el, table_placeholder);

      $('.table-render-preview').dataTable({
        "destroy": true,
        aaSorting: []
      });
    }
  }
});

/* eslint-disable no-new */
new Vue({
  el: '#datatables-admin',
  template: '<App/>',
  components: { App }
});
```

[App.vue](https://github.com/GhitaB/datatables-admin/blob/master/src/App.vue)

```
<template>
  <div id="datatables-admin">
    <h1>Datatables admin</h1>

    <table id="editor">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th v-for="(column, index_col) in columns" :key="index_col">
            <i class="fas fa-long-arrow-alt-left fa-2x dta-btn move-col-left" title="Move column to left" v-on:click="move_col_to_left(index_col)"></i>
            <i class="fas fa-long-arrow-alt-right fa-2x dta-btn move-col-right" title="Move column to right" v-on:click="move_col_to_right(index_col)"></i>
            <i class="fas fa-plus fa-2x dta-btn add-col" title="Add a column after this one" v-on:click="add_col(index_col + 1)"></i>
            <i class="fas fa-times fa-2x dta-btn delete-col" title="Delete this column" v-on:click="delete_col(index_col)"></i>
            <br />
            <editable :content="columns[index_col]" v-on:update="update_col($event, index_col)"></editable>
          </th>
          <th>
            <i class="fas fa-plus fa-2x dta-btn add-col" title="Add a column" v-on:click="add_col(0)"></i>
            <i class="fas fa-plus fa-2x dta-btn add-row" title="Add a row" v-on:click="add_row(0)"></i>
            <i class="fas fa-times fa-2x dta-btn delete-all-cols" title="Delete all columns" v-on:click="delete_all_cols"></i>
            <i class="fas fa-times fa-2x dta-btn delete-all-rows" title="Delete all rows" v-on:click="delete_all_rows"></i>
          </th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr v-for="(row, index_row) in rows" :key="index_row">
          <td v-for="(column, index_col) in columns" :key="index_col">
            <editable :content="rows[index_row][index_col]" v-on:update="update_row($event, index_row, index_col)"></editable>
          <td>
            <i class="fas fa-long-arrow-alt-up fa-2x dta-btn move-row-up" v-on:click="move_row_up(index_row)" title="Move row up"></i>
            <i class="fas fa-long-arrow-alt-down fa-2x dta-btn move-row-down" v-on:click="move_row_down(index_row)" title="Move row down"></i>
            <i class="fas fa-plus fa-2x dta-btn add-row" title="Add a row under this one" v-on:click="add_row(index_row + 1)"></i>
            <i class="fas fa-times fa-2x dta-btn delete-row" title="Delete this row" v-on:click="delete_row(index_row)"></i>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>

    <div>
      <b>DEBUG:</b>
      <span v-text="rows"></span>
    </div>

    <table-preview></table-preview>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'app',
  data() {
    return {
      LOREM: "Click me to edit",
      NONE: "",
      columns: ['Click me to edit', 'Demo column 2', 'Demo column 3', 'URL'],
      rows: [
        ['col1 data1', 'col2 data1', 'col3 data1', 'https://www.google.com'],
        ['col1 data2', 'col2 data2', 'col3 data2', 'https://www.yahoo.com']
      ]
    }
  },
  methods: {
    refresh: function() {
      this.$forceUpdate();
    },
    update_col: function(content, col_index) {
      this.columns[col_index] = content;
      this.refresh();
    },
    update_row: function(content, row_index, col_index) {
      this.rows[row_index][col_index] = content;
      this.refresh();
    },
    add_col: function(col_index) {
      // Add a new column at given index
      this.columns.splice(col_index, 0, this.LOREM);
      for(var i = 0; i < this.rows.length; i++) {
        var row = this.rows[i];
        row.splice(col_index, 0, this.NONE);
      }
      this.refresh();
    },
    delete_col: function(col_index, skip_confirm = false) {
      if(!skip_confirm) {
        var result = confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this column?");
        if(!result) {
          return;
        }
      }
      // Remove column
      this.columns.splice(col_index, 1);
      // Remove related items in rows
      for(var i = 0; i < this.rows.length; i++) {
        var row = this.rows[i];
        row.splice(col_index, 1);
      }
      this.refresh();
    },
    add_row: function(row_index) {
      // Add a new row at given index
      this.rows.splice(row_index, 0, new Array(this.columns.length));
      for(var i = 0; i < this.columns.length; i++) {
        this.rows[row_index][i] = this.NONE;
      }
      this.refresh();
    },
    delete_row: function(row_index, skip_confirm = false) {
      if(!skip_confirm) {
        var result = confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this row?");
        if(!result) {
          return;
        }
      }
      this.rows.splice(row_index, 1);
      this.refresh();
    },
    delete_all_rows: function() {
      var result = confirm("Are you sure you want to delete all rows?");
      if(!result) {
        return;
      }
      var nr_rows = this.rows.length;
      for(var i = 0; i < nr_rows; i++) {
        this.delete_row(0, true);
      }
      this.refresh();
    },
    delete_all_cols: function() {
      var result = confirm("Are you sure you want to delete all columns?");
      if(!result) {
        return;
      }
      var nr_cols = this.columns.length;
      for(var i = 0; i < nr_cols; i++) {
        this.delete_col(0, true);
      }
      this.refresh();
    },
    move_col_to_left: function(col_index) {
      if(col_index == 0) {
        return;
      }
      var temp = this.columns[col_index - 1];
      this.columns[col_index - 1] = this.columns[col_index];
      this.columns[col_index] = temp;
      for(var i = 0; i < this.rows.length; i++) {
        temp = this.rows[i][col_index - 1];
        this.rows[i][col_index - 1] = this.rows[i][col_index];
        this.rows[i][col_index] = temp;
      }
      this.refresh();
    },
    move_col_to_right: function(col_index) {
      if(col_index == this.columns.length - 1) {
        return;
      }
      var temp = this.columns[col_index + 1];
      this.columns[col_index + 1] = this.columns[col_index];
      this.columns[col_index] = temp;
      for(var i = 0; i < this.rows.length; i++) {
        temp = this.rows[i][col_index + 1];
        this.rows[i][col_index + 1] = this.rows[i][col_index];
        this.rows[i][col_index] = temp;
      }
      this.refresh();
    },
    move_row_up: function(row_index) {
      if(row_index == 0) {
        return;
      }
      var temp = this.rows[row_index - 1];
      this.rows[row_index - 1] = this.rows[row_index];
      this.rows[row_index] = temp;
      this.refresh();
    },
    move_row_down: function(row_index) {
      if(row_index == this.rows.length - 1) {
        return;
      }
      var temp = this.rows[row_index + 1];
      this.rows[row_index + 1] = this.rows[row_index];
      this.rows[row_index] = temp;
      this.refresh();
    }
  }
}
</script>

<style>
/* https://coolors.co/96adc8-d7ffab-fcff6c-d89d6a-6d454c
   #FFFFFF #EEEEEE #757575 #000000 #bfd630 #A0B228 #819110
*/
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans|Tangerine');
body.dta {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  background: #EEEEEE;
  color: #000000;
}
body.dta div#datatables-admin {
  background: #FFFFFF;
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 20px;
}
body.dta div#datatables-admin h1 {
  font-family: 'Tangerine', cursive;
  color: #000000;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 86px;
  font-weight: 500;
  margin: 20px;
}
body.dta div#datatables-admin table#editor {
  background: #EEEEEE;
  border-spacing: 5px;
  color: #000000;
  margin: auto;
}
body.dta div#datatables-admin table#editor tr,
body.dta div#datatables-admin table#editor td,
body.dta div#datatables-admin table#editor th {
  background: #FFFFFF;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 5px;
  text-align: center;
}
body.dta div#datatables-admin table#editor th {
  user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -khtml-user-select: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -o-user-select: none;
}
body.dta div#datatables-admin .dta-btn {
  color: #A0B228;
  user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -khtml-user-select: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -o-user-select: none;
}
body.dta div#datatables-admin .dta-btn:hover {
  color: #819110;
  cursor: pointer;
}
body.dta div#datatables-admin div.table-preview-container {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 40px;
}
body.dta div#datatables-admin table.table-render-preview {
  margin: auto;
}
body.dta div#datatables-admin button.render-table {
  margin-bottom: 40px;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 6px;
  background: #A0B228;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  border: none;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 900;
}
body.dta div#datatables-admin button.render-table:hover {
  background: #819110;
  cursor: pointer;
}
body.dta a {
  color: #A0B228;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: 900;
}
body.dta a:hover {
  color: #819110;
}
</style>
```

Update:

Maybe related to how I force refresh the things:

```
refresh: function() {
  this.$forceUpdate();
},
```

Comment: I always try to not use index as key in v-for, it could cause some problem. Have you tried to manually generate a numeric key every time you create a column/row and use it as key instead of index?

Comment: Something to do with your data reactivity since those are arrays? Have you tried replacing `rows` & `columns` variables right after modifying them? i.e. `rows = rows.slice()`

Comment: @i--, I tried now: https://github.com/GhitaB/datatables-admin/commit/2569afc29d33d5a230b29d8e3613cf7247eae3a0 The problem is still here.

Comment: @Fabio, I will try. Thank you.

Comment: @Fabio, I'm not sure how to use it. Tried this way: https://github.com/GhitaB/datatables-admin/commit/3035daa25fa7b430df151b636d358786f1b17c69

Should I use genUniqueKey(index) everywhere I use the index now?

Comment: @GhitaB the best solution is to use an array of object for rows and columns, where each object has the property `key` (which you manually initialized). But this will change a lot of your code logic.

Comment: @Fabio, thank you. No problem, I will try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved as @Fabio suggested by adding an id for all cells data, then using it as a key in v-for.

Before:

```
<th v-for="(column, index_col) in columns" :key="index_col">
```

After:

```
<th v-for="(column, index_col) in columns" :key="column.id">
```

My data before (simplified):

```
['cell text 1', 'cell text 2']
```

My data now:

```
[{'id': '123123', 'text': 'cell text 1'}, {'id': '34353453', 'text': 'cell text 2'}]
```

It seems related: [Why not always use the index as the key in a vue.js for loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44531510/why-not-always-use-the-index-as-the-key-in-a-vue-js-for-loop)