# [Vue warn]: Avoid using non-primitive value as key, use string/number value instead

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm building a clone of HackerNews and am getting the following error:

```
vue.esm.js?efeb:591 [Vue warn]: Avoid using non-primitive value as key, use string/number value instead.

found in

---> <Single> at src/components/Single.vue
       <App> at src/App.vue
         <Root>
```

The error seems to be coming from Single.vue but I can't work what it is? The template is as follows:

```
<template>
    <div class="container">
        <h2>{{ story.title }}</h2>
        <p>Score: {{ story.score }}</p>
        <p>{{ story.url }}</p>
        <div v-for="comment in comments" :key="comment">
          <div class="comment-wrap">
                <div class="comment-block">
                    <p class="comment-text">{{ comment.text }}</p>
                    <div class="bottom-comment">
                        <div class="comment-author">{{ comment.by }}</div>
                        <div class="comment-date">{{ comment.time }}</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
```

If anyone out there can help, that would be great!?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can simply avoid the use of `:key` in your `v-for`.

```
...
<div v-for="comment in comments">
...
```

As vuejs [documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#key) said:

> It is recommended to provide a key with v-for whenever possible, unless the
> iterated DOM content is simple, or you are intentionally relying on the
> default behavior for performance gains.

Comment: This is working but it result whit IDE warning "Element in iteration expect to have v-bind:key derictives"

Comment: It is recommended to follow the guidelines. Why you not use a computed propety to return a comment in string format? :key="getComents(comment)". That works.

Answer (score 77):

Other answers work, but the following is also worth a try:

```html
<div v-for="(comment, idx) in comments" :key="idx">
  <!-- ... -->
</div>
```

Comment: Index should only be used as key when you are sure the array content is immutable though.

Answer (score 34):

The warning sources from `<div v-for="comment in comments" :key="comment">`, where the object `comment` is used as a `key` for `v-for`. The meaning of the warning is quite literal, don't use Object as key.

Use unique primitive value as key, maybe something like `comment.id` or `${comment.time}${comment.by}`

Comment: This one actually makes sense.

Comment: thanks, this should have been the answer as it removed my warning message.

Answer (score 9):

Below is an example of what works for me. Hope that helps

[image]

Comment: Not recommended as explained here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44531510/why-not-always-use-the-index-as-the-key-in-a-vue-js-for-loop

Answer (score 8):

Use unique primitive value as key,
It is recommended to provide a `key` attribute with `v-for` whenever possible.

> like `:key="design.uniqueId"`

```
<li v-for="design in designs" :key="design.id">
    <!-- code -->
</li>

<li v-for="loop in loops" :key="loop.id">
    <!-- code -->
</li>
```

Such as [Vue.js Documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#Maintaining-State)

Answer (score 2):

as per vue js [Maintaining State](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#Maintaining-State) Doc it says your id is find multiple times

That means your code should look like this

`div v-for="comment in comments" :key="comment.id">`

insted of

`div v-for="comment in comments" :key="comment">`

To give Vue a hint so that it can track each node’s identity, and thus reuse and reorder existing elements, you need to provide a unique key attribute for each item

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are using an Object type as the key, if it can be converted into a unique string, use the string instead of the instance by calling such as `toString`.

I had same issue when I used `mongoose.Types.ObjectId()` as the key, after I changed to `mongoose.Types.ObjectId().toHexString()` the warning disappear.