# Vue v-for keys and values

Tags: vue.js

I have the following JSON:

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "title": "a title here",
            "news_url": "https://someurl",
            "sentiment": "Neutral",
            "type": "Article"
        },
        {
            "title": "a title here",
            "news_url": "https://someurl",
            "sentiment": "Negative",
            "type": "Article"
        },
        {
            "title": "a title here",
            "news_url": "https://someurl",
            "sentiment": "Neutral",
            "type": "Article"
        }
    ]
}
```

I have defined my data object 'news' like so:

```
data() {
   return {
     news: [],
  };
},
```

Now I am trying to v-for through these values so that I can get 3 divs each with the `title` value.

I am trying the following but I really don;t have much of a clue:

```
 <div v-for = "title in news">
     {{ title }}
</div>
```

I get the error:  Elements in iteration expect to have 'v-bind:key' directives.

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: I guess u don't have id in news array.. Add index 
<div v-for="(title, index) in news" :key="index" >
    {{ title }}
</div>

You can refer this link for more usage of index - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44531510/why-not-always-use-the-index-as-the-key-in-a-vue-js-for-loop

Comment: Vue requires :key
https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#Maintaining-State

Comment: Thanks Viresh. I have tried your solution here: https://jsfiddle.net/Lf69b8vq/1/

Something is happening but it prints out the numbers 1,2,3 instead of the titles.

Comment: Thanks, It works now when do {{ index.title }} instead of {{ title }} - https://jsfiddle.net/de0xhap6/

Answer (score 2):

Vue [documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html) indicate:

> It is recommended to provide a key attribute with v-for whenever
> possible, unless the iterated DOM content is simple, or you are
> intentionally relying on the default behavior for performance gains.
>
> Since it’s a generic mechanism for Vue to identify nodes, the key also
> has other uses that are not specifically tied to v-for, as we will see
> later in the guide.

> Don’t use non-primitive values like objects and arrays as v-for keys.
> Use string or numeric values instead.

Then you should use the `key` directive binding it with string or numeric value like this:

```
<div v-for = "(title, index) in news" :key="index">
     {{ title }}
</div>
```