# Using image props - vue

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js

I am trying to show images through v-for, but they do not appear.

```js
<div v-for="(n, i) in images" :key="i">
    <v-img :src="{n}"></v-img>
</div>

...

images: [
     '../assets/thirdSection/Olivia.png',
     '../assets/thirdSection/Olivia.png',
     '../assets/thirdSection/luiz.png',
]
```

Comment: You really should not use `i` for the `:key`, it will be worse than using nothing.

Comment: @kissu Where are you reading that from? That’s totally untrue. As long as `i` is a string, it is actually recommended to use it as the key.

Comment: @Terry based on how it works essentially, but this is a good source to corroborate my tellings: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44531545/8816585

Comment: please share your folder structure (where the componet is related to the images)

Comment: please show the full component code

Answer (score 3):

You do not need to use `{}`
juse remove those brackets from your `:src` binding

```js
<div v-for="(n, i) in images" :key="i">
    <v-img :src="n"></v-img>
</div>

...

images: [
     '../assets/thirdSection/Olivia.png',
     '../assets/thirdSection/Olivia.png',
     '../assets/thirdSection/luiz.png',
]
```

Comment: man, still not going. I tested it to see if the image path is correct and yes, it is. But it still doesn't appear

Comment: @VitorLucenti is your path correct ? Try to display one (just grab the first index) before trying to loop on the array. `<v-img :src="images[0]"></v-img>`

Comment: you probably need to use `~/assets`

Comment: Nothing yet guys :(
The image path is right

Comment: Is vuetify properly installed ? Check it with a regular `<img>` tag.

Comment: I put the img tag and also nothing. Vuetify is installed correctly yes, i am using it now

Comment: `img` tag should be working, at least. Post some images of your project tree (edit your question), probably the path.

Answer (score 0):

Try using [require](https://nodejs.org/en/knowledge/getting-started/what-is-require/) to load your local images:

```
<div v-for="(n, i) in images" :key="i">
    <v-img :src="require(n)"></v-img>
</div>

...

images: [
     '@/assets/thirdSection/Olivia.png',
     '@/assets/thirdSection/Olivia.png',
     '@/assets/thirdSection/luiz.png',
]
```

You just have to install [file-loader](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/file-loader) to your modules and configure your webpack.

Doing it like that, your local image path is resolved into a url.