# Stuck while going through this array in VueJS

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, nuxt.js

Maybe this is an already answered question somewhere but I still couldn't figure out the solution for this simple problem. How do I use v-for to loop through this JSON object and print each car brand alongside with the "inStock" value?

```js
carStore: [
  {
    Brand: {
      id: 1,
      name: 'some name',
    },
    inStock: 50,
  },

  {
    Brand: {
      id: 2,
      name: 'some name',
    },
    inStock: 100,
  },

  {
    Brand: {
      id: 3,
      name: 'some name',
    },
    inStock: 0,
  },
]
```

Comment: Can't you have simply `brand` rather than `brandOne` and so on ?

Comment: Unfortunately not. All the brands should be inside a "brands" object but I posted the data this way for simplicity.

Comment: Can't you just move `BrandOne` to `brand`, `BrandTwo` to `brand` and `BrandThree` to `brand`? You're short-circuiting some conventions in terms of JSON structure there, hence the difficulty to loop on those object keys. It is doable this way, but very error prone.

Comment: Didn't notice I typed it like that, thanks for pointing it. But that's the way I'm stuck anyways

Comment: I mean, you can have `brand` or you only can have `brand{digitName}`? If 2nd choice, why are so "stuck" this way? Are you doing the API or do you use some external one here?

Comment: Getting the data from django and trying to adapt it to vue on the frontend. Too much coffe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your data structure edited, it can look like this

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <div v-for="{ inStock, Brand: { name, id } } in carStore" :key="id">
      <span>{{ name }}: {{ inStock }}</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      carStore: [
        {
          Brand: {
            id: 1,
            name: 'some name',
          },
          inStock: 50,
        },

        {
          Brand: {
            id: 2,
            name: 'some name',
          },
          inStock: 100,
        },

        {
          Brand: {
            id: 3,
            name: 'some name',
          },
          inStock: 0,
        },
      ],
    }
  },
}
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

If you are allowed to change the data structure, I would recommend you do like this:

```json
"carStore":[
   {
      "id":1,
      "name":"some name",
      "inStock":50
   },
   {
      "id":2,
      "name":"some name",
      "inStock":100
   },
   {
      "id":3,
      "name":"some name",
      "inStock":0
   }
]
```

Then you can iterate in Vue like this:

```html
<div v-for="(item, key) in carStore" :key="key">
    id:  {{item.id}} - name: {{item.name}} - instock: {{item.inStock}}
</div>
```

Comment: That's how I started but had to change the logic so I can just increment or decrement the quantity in stock on a specific brand based on the id.

Comment: Please do not recommend using the `:key` with the index of an array... Especially when OP provides an ID.

Comment: @ChickenChoker You can still do that

Comment: @kissu Please educate me on why it is not recommended to use the index which is guaranteed to be unique?

Comment: @tauzN this is not guaranteed to be unique, that's the point. Here is a possible answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44531545/8816585 If you add 1, remove 1, add 1. Do you think that the latest 1 will be unique ? More that this, if you have a list of 10 elements, and you remove the 2nd one, do you think that all elements following (3rd, 4th etc...) will have fixed ID ? Nope, because the ID: 2 will be removed, hence the next ones will all be offset by 1. Which is counter productive in a way of all indexes being changed for every element in the loop.