# How to exclude an item in v-for loop?

Tags: vue.js

How can I exclude the item in the loop with type that is equal to "hidden" in Vue?

```
<span v-for="(customField, index) in item.customFields" :key="index">
{{ customField.value }}
</span>
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should create a computed value that filters items for render.

**In your case:**

**Composition API:**

```
const customFieldsToRender = computed(() => item.value?.customFields?.filter((f) => f.type !== "hidden")) || [];
```

**Options API:**

```
customFieldsToRender() {
  return this.item?.customFields?.filter((f) => f.type !== "hidden")) || [];
}
```

And then render fields by this computed value

```
<span v-for="(customField, index) in customFieldsToRender" :key="index">
{{ customField.value }}
</span>
```

Also, I see you use index as a key in v-for loop. It is a bad practice. Here is well explained why it is - [Why not always use the index as the key in a vue.js for loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44531510/why-not-always-use-the-index-as-the-key-in-a-vue-js-for-loop)

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative, if you don't want to create a new computed list, you can use `<template>` which won't render to anything:

```
<template v-for="(customField, index) in item.customFields" :key="index">
  <span v-if="item.type!=='hidden'">
    {{ customField.value }}
  </span>
</template>
```

Note that you shouldn't use v-if and v-for on the same element!
https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/conditional.html#v-if-with-v-for

Also not that using index as your key (as you do in your code) is considered bad-practice. This can give you unwanted results if your list changes. Use `item.value` in your case.