# Getting multiple properties of an object based on matching ID and outputting them without reducing multiple times

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

I'm curious if there's a better way of getting properties from a reduced object within a Vue  or wrapper DOM element.

For example, I have these two data objects in my component:

```js
player: [{
   active: true,
   id: 0,
   name: "Alfred",
   action: 0
}, {
   active: true,
   id: 1,
   name: "Bruce",
   action: 1
}],
actions: [{
   id: 0,
   label: "Give advice",
   description: "Player advises others"
}, {
   id: 1,
   label: "Fight",
   description: "Player fights enemy"
}]
```

...and I'd like to loop through a list of options and return all results, with properties of the action within each player:

```
------------------------------------------------------------------
Active?   ID    Name     Label         Description
------------------------------------------------------------------
true      0     Alfred   Give Advice   Player advises others
true      1     Bruce    Fight         Player fights enemy
```

I know I can loop through the players like so:

```html
<table>
  <tr v-for="(player, index) in players" :key="index">
    <td>{{ player.active }}</td>
    <td>{{ player.id }}</td>
    <td>{{ this.getActionProp(player.action, 'label') }}</td>
    <td>{{ this.getActionProp(player.action, 'description') }}</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

With a method like this:

```js
getActionProp(id, prop){
  return this.actions.reduce((acc, cur) => {
    return cur.id == id ? cur[prop] : acc
  }, {})
}
```

But it seems like that has to reduce twice for each row in the table. Is there a better way to get these props or at least to make it so they only reduce once per row?

Something like:

```html
<table>
  <tr v-for="(player, index) in players" :key="index">
    <td>{{ player.active }}</td>
    <td>{{ player.id }}</td>
    <template :action="getAction(player.action)">
      <td>{{ action.label }}</td>
      <td>{{ action.description }}</td>
    </template>
  </tr>
</table>
```

with `getAction()` being a method that reduces and returns the matching action object.

Thank you for your time and I appreciate your guidance.

Comment: **If possible, avoid using array `index` for the `:key` value**, as it may happen that you insert a new element, for example, into the middle of a 10-element array at position 5, and from then on, the saved values will shift for elements with an index greater than 5. Instead, try using a fixed "key" that uniquely identifies that record in the array, regardless of whether it is in the 1st, 5th, 10th, etc. position. This will save you from some inconveniences, such as when sorting the array elements.

Comment: [Maintaining State with `key`](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/list.html#maintaining-state-with-key) -- [**Why not always use the `index` as the `key`** in a vue.js for loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44531510/why-not-always-use-the-index-as-the-key-in-a-vue-js-for-loop)

Comment: Thank you. I didn't know that. Maybe the player.id would've been better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just just map the actions in a computed and prepare the table rows:

[Vue SFC Playground](https://play.vuejs.org/#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)

```html
<script setup>
import { computed, reactive } from 'vue'

const players = reactive([{
  active: true,
  id: 0,
  name: "Alfred",
  action: 0
}, {
  active: true,
  id: 1,
  name: "Bruce",
  action: 1
}])

const actions = reactive([{
  id: 0,
  label: "Give advice",
  description: "Player advises others"
}, {
  id: 1,
  label: "Fight",
  description: "Player fights enemy"
}])

const playerTable = computed(() => players.map(player => {
  return {
    ...player,
    action: actions.find(action => action.id === player.action)
  }
}))
</script>

<template>
  <h1>TEST</h1>
  <table>
    <tr v-for="player in playerTable" :key="player.id">
      <td>{{ player.active }}</td>
      <td>{{ player.id }}</td>
      <td>{{ player.action.label }}</td>
      <td>{{ player.action.description }}</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</template>
```

Comment: That's such simple, elegant solution. Thank you so much!

Comment: @BenCoffin you are welcome :) dont forget to accept my answer (the checkbox) and upvote it (the arrow up), thanks!

Comment: Done! I just implemented your answer and it worked like a charm. Thanks again.