# two v-for loops with same key value

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I'm trying to make a todo web page with Vue and some todos are from GitHub Issues and another group is created in the browser by the user inputs. The problem is that both of them have as key value the index of the array where I store the title of the todos.

Below is some of my code:

The v-for elements

```html
<TodoItem
  v-for="(todo, index) in todos"
  :key="index"
  :title="todo"
  @delTodo="removeTodo(index)"
/>
<TodoItem
  v-for="(issue, index) in issues"
  :key="index"
  :title="issue.title"
  @delTodo="closeIssue(index)"
/>
```

The data of my component

```js
export default {
  name: 'TodosIssues',
  components: {
    TodoItem
  },
  data() {
    return {
      todoKeys: 0,
      todo: '',
      todos: [],
      issues: []
    }
  }
}
```

The TodoItem Component

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <el-col :span="12">
      <el-card class="box-card" shadow="hover" style="margin: 5px 0">
        <el-row :gutter="12">
          <el-col :span="21">{{ todo }}</el-col>
          <el-col :span="3">
            <el-button
              type="success"
              icon="el-icon-check"
              circle
              @click="$emit('delTodo')"
            ></el-button>
          </el-col>
        </el-row>
      </el-card>
    </el-col>
  </div>
</template>
```

```js
export default {
  name: 'TodoItem',
  props: {
    title: String
  },
  data() {
    return {
      todo: ''
    }
  },
  created() {
    this.todo = this.title
  },
  methods: {}
}
```

I tried to add the index of the local todos to the issues todos but my web page breaks.
I know that can not use duplicated key values but I don't know what other thing I can do.

Comment: It's not clear at all why using an index value for your two different v-for loops is causing an issue.  Where is the issue occurring?  Is it in `removeTodo` or `closeIssue`? You've not shown these.  The "duplicated" key values is probably not the root cause...  The loops are completely separate. The fact they both use an index key does not inherently cause an issue.  It _is_ a problem for **any** v-for loop where the array changes (items being added, removed, sorted, etc.) to use index keys.  Use any unique value for the key instead, usually some `id` field.  If you don't have one, make one.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/44531510/6225326 for more information