# Nuxt 3/Vue 3 Reactivity issue, while rendering component in v-for loop

Tags: javascript, vue.js, frontend, nuxt.js

Hey community :) I have a reactivity issue (I think it is about reactivity).

### Description

I have `FileInput.vue` component. With that component I upload files to project. When the new image is added, the new field is pushing to the `form.allImages reactive` array:

```js
@add="addImageField"
```

addImageField function:

```js
const addImageField = (): void => {
  form.allImages.push({ filename: '' });
};
```

Reactive data:

```js
import type { Images } from '@/types/images.d';

interface Work {
  allImages: Images[];
}

const form: Work = reactive({
  allImages: [{ filename: '' }],
});
```

### Problem description

When I add 2 images and then try to delete the first one using:

```js
const deleteImageField = (index: number): void => {
   form.allImages.splice(index, 1);
};
```

the first block is removing correctly and the second comes up to its place (it is correct), but now the second image block need to be empty(with clear value to be able to add image to that). The value of the second element in `form.allImages` is clear, but the component block is not empty, there remains the image of the block that now is the first element in the array.

Image: [https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt/assets/73745478/74981582-05ea-4910-9387-7240dc4394c2](https://stackoverflow.com)

### Reproduction

https://stackblitz.com/edit/nuxt-starter-qeaeuf?file=app.vue
Here is the reproduction.

### How to use the reproduction

Click to the `Add Image` block and choose any image from your PC and there will be shown `static favicon.ico` file just for the example. And there will appear the `Delete` button for deleting that image. Above all the blocks you can see the `{{ form.allImages }}` data block for tracking data.

### How it is supposed to work

After the delete the image block with empty value need to be empty(without any image, and be able for the user to upload image).

**Thank you for the attention. Please help if you can :)

P.S. If you have any ideas of making that code better, write it too. Thank you.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [key](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/list.html#maintaining-state-with-key) of your `v-for` needs to be on the same element as the `v-for`.  Not only that, but you [should not use `index` as your `v-for` key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44531510). The key should be a unique value. When you have an array where elements are being added and removed, the item at each index can change, meaning the index is not a unique identifier for the given item. This is the reason the UI is not updating correctly. Vue is not able to properly diff the changes to the array based on the key.

One simple way to correct this is to add a unique `id` field based on a counter variable that increases every time you push to your array.

```js
interface Images {
  filename: string
  id: number
}

let count = ref(0);
const form: Work = reactive({
  allImages: [{ id: count.value++, filename: '' }],
});

const addImageField = (): void => {
  form.allImages.push({ id: count.value++, filename: '' });
};
```

Then your v-for should be:

```html
<div v-for="(image, index) in form.allImages" :key="image.id"
```

[Updated StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/nuxt-starter-u1cnbo?file=app.vue,components%2FFileInput.vue,components%2FButton.vue)

---

Few other problems corrected:

```js
const { text, required, modelValue } = props;
```

1. [Do not destructure props](https://vuejs.org/api/composition-api-setup.html#accessing-props). This will cause these values to lose their reactivity. If you're in the `setup()` function you can access them with `props.propName`.  Or outside the setup function as `this.propName`, or in the template code as just `propName`.  You also don't have to return props from the setup function. They are automatically returned for you.
2. You should rename your custom Button component.  "Button" is the reserved name in HTML for the native `<button>` element.

Comment: Yes, it is working now, thank you for the answer and the advices :).